# php creating DOM element and sending with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, dom

I just started writing server code (php), I finished the client side with javascript and html. I have some questions that I hope to get some clarification on before I start coding the server side.

Is it possible/a good idea to create DOM elements (`img`, `p`, `header` etc) on the server side (php), send it to the client side via AJAX, client side set some extra attribute and 'attach' it (the received DOM) to a `div` on that html page?

I want this because those DOM elements will be used on multiple pages.

Is it possible, and if possible, is sending the entire DOM efficient?

Comment: I think using some templatting engine would achieve what you want more elegantly

Comment: When you say "DOM element", do you mean the HTML markup? Because it's not possible to send a DOM element from the server to the client; you can send the markup, which the client will parse and translate into actual DOM elements.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I think he meaning that :D

Comment: so i should learn xml too?

Comment: Either way, you'll have to send it as a string. _How_ you make that string it up to you.

Comment: @user308553 No, you can send HTML.

Comment: @Wrikken wait, what about image? I am going to have user upload photos and post it on pages. How does that work? is it a matter of sending and receiving a link(string) to the image or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sending raw HTML rather than JSON you want to consider things like:

- the size of the request is going to be bigger. JSON is much more succinct
- the time to render the element is going to be shorter (no need to parse the JSON and render the HTML, you're already done it server side)
- reusability and caching is pretty easy. Indeed, The same snippet could be served to multiple clients and the template can be cached (the same is true if you used precompiled template in JS, but it's slightly more complex).
- Code logic is all in one place (server side) or in two places (JS and server side).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to accomplish what you want is using a [Template Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine), which out there are plenty of them.

This way you can have separate files for the templates and load them as necessary via an AJAX request.

I recommend you the use of [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), its pretty simple and you can use it with JavaScript and also with PHP itself!!!

See the PHP Handlebars port here: https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php

Comment: I'd also recommend Mustach.js < mustache.github.io > also a powerful logicless template engine

Comment: @KhalidDabjan: I agree with you :) Both are powerfull logicless template engines. I think Yehuda Katz inspired itself in Mustache for doing Handlebars.

Comment: PHP _is_ a template engine (well, it is one of its capabilities), unless you have people dabbling making templates with no knowledge of PHP, there's seldom use for an template engine with Yet Another Syntax.

Comment: @Wrikken: I agree with you on the part that PHP is itself a template engine but not on the last part. Never say never since rarelly you will have the knowledge to see all the use cases that can arises for a particular tech. For instance I make a good use of Handlebars both in JavaScript and with PHP in a WordPress plugin I've been developing.

Comment: Well, _javascript sided_ templates are OK to me, because that's hardly built in. Aside from that, I have never seen something working better, faster, or more easily maintainable on the server side of PHP.

Comment: @Wrikken: I agreed with you but we aren't discussing that, but the need of using another template engine besides plain PHP. I come with a valid use case which proves that need which the same creation of the Handlebars' PHP port acknoledges that.